# Accessing class member creates access violation

Tags: c++, qt

i have a QT cpp class defined as such:

```
class signalTapSignalAggregator : public  QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    signalTapSignalAggregator();
    void addSignalTapSignal(signalTapSignal &signalTapSignalInst);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    int numberOfRow;
private:
    QVector<signalTapSignal> listOfSignals;

};



signalTapSignalAggregator::signalTapSignalAggregator()
{
numberOfRow = 0;
}

void signalTapSignalAggregator::addSignalTapSignal(signalTapSignal &signalTapSignalInst){
int sizeOfSignal = signalTapSignalInst.getSignalLength();
if(sizeOfSignal >= 0){
    try{
        numberOfRow= signalTapSignalInst.getSignalLength();
    }catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        qDebug() << "Caught Exception" ;

    }
}
listOfSignals.push_back(signalTapSignalInst);
}

int signalTapSignalAggregator::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const{
return numberOfRow;
}

 int signalTapSignalAggregator::columnCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const{
return listOfSignals.size();
 }

QVariant signalTapSignalAggregator::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const{
QString fieldName;

switch(role){
    case Qt::DisplayRole:

        fieldName = listOfSignals.at(index.column()).feildName;

        break;
    case Qt::DecorationRole:
        break;
    case Qt::EditRole:
        break;
    case Qt::ToolTipRole:
        break;
    case Qt::StatusTipRole:
        break;
    case Qt::WhatsThisRole:
        break;
    case Qt::SizeHintRole:
        break;
}

return fieldName;
}
```

The function addSignalTapSignal is invoking a access violation when i attemp to set member variable numberOfRow in the function addSignalTapSignal()

The error message i recieve is:

> The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception
>
> Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception as 0x7ff6c2a586ac, code 0xC0000005: write access violation at 0x1, flags=0x0.

from my perspective all i am doing is trying to write to a member variable in the class signalTapSignalAggregator

I have no clue what i am doing wrong...

I have a suspicion that the instance of the class signalTapSignalAggregator has not been initialized correctly...

```
signalTapSignalAggregator *signalTapSignalAggregatorInst = new signalTapSignalAggregator();
signalTapParser *signalTapParserInst = new signalTapParser(signalTapSignalAggregatorInst);
```

the class signalTapParser has  refrence to signalTapSignalAggregator and it calls the method addSignalTapSignal() and the access violation occurs when i the function addSignalTapSignal() is invoked...

Comment: First of all you should run in a debugger to locate where the crash happens in *your* code. When it does, then check all involved variables to see that their values are looking okay.

Comment: i have done this and the line numberOfRow= signalTapSignalInst.getSignalLength(); inside addSignalTapSignal() is where this access violation occurs.....

Comment: In the debugger, look at the value of `this`, then backtrace a level to find where you are using the null pointer.

Comment: @kfsone It doesn't have to be a null pointer, it could simply be a case of using uninitialized local variables somewhere.

Comment: @user254340: Have you simply tried `void signalTapSignalAggregator::addSignalTapSignal(signalTapSignal &signalTapSignalInst){ numberOfRow = 3; }`